# if and only if condition for a function to be a Lebesgue Integrable.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Given a function $f(x)$ over any closed interval $[a,b]$, does there is any if and only if condition so that function will be Lebesgue Integrable.

For Riemann integrability  there is a condition that

> *A function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff the function is continuous almost everywhere.*

Thankyou

Comment: On a bounded interval or more generally a set of finite measure a bounded function is Lebesgue integrable if and only if it is measurable.

Comment: it doen't matter whether the set is open or closed?

Comment: Other statements can be made for unbounded functions and/or infinite measure sets which are not as concise and do not have a Riemann counterpart. The Riemann integral is not defined in these cases.

Comment: The set over which the integral is taken can be open or closed or neither. It has to be measurable though.  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3216799/148510) may be of interest.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.

Comment: A good reference is Real Analysis by Royden.